# mwlib list articles

Tags: python, wikipedia

I'm trying to use [`mwlib`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mwlib) (a semi-official Python library) to parse Wikipedia and do some text-mining. So far I've not found any official documentation, and have had to rely on Google, the odd mailinglist post and wading through the source code.

Does anyone know a way of getting a list of Wikipedia articles through `mwlib`? Or if there's an alternative way that doesn't use `mwlib` that's good too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help you but do a quick search for `wikipedia` at [pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi).

Maybe some of the result may help you.

I stumbled upon [mwlib documentation](http://pediapress.com/code/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've checked that particular mwlib page, and the documentation is all to do with their command-line tools, not on how to use the Python library itself (at least as far as I can see).

Answer (score 0):

Another python library available is [wikitools](http://code.google.com/p/python-wikitools/wiki/wikitools). There is some documentation in pydoc, but it's not much.